# Height of singlespaced marginnote in a onehalfspaced document

Tags: spacing, marginnote

I have a onehalfspaced document in which I want to put marginal notes that again should be singlespaced. See this example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\newcommand{\sspmarginnote}[1]{\marginnote{\singlespacing #1}}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
\sspmarginnote{Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat}
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{document}
```

As you can see the note starts below the point where it was issued. I fixed this badly by inserting some arbitrary negative space:

```
\newcommand{\sspmarginnote}[1]{%
  \marginnote{\vspace{-2\baselineskip}\singlespacing #1}
}
```

but I can imagine that the undesired vertical offset differs from case to case. So this fix isn't really an option. How would you do this properly?

Comment: How about `\newcommand{\sspmarginnote}[1]{\marginnote{\singlespacing #1}[-2.66\baselineskip]}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems quite stable to me. Give it a try:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\newcommand{\sspmarginnote}[1]{\marginnote{\begin{spacing}{1}\vspace{-\baselineskip}\RaggedRight #1\end{spacing}}}

\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    \sspmarginnote{Duis au-tem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat}
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks stable indeed. +1 if I could. The site returned an error that I can't upvote yet...

Comment: @r_joh Glad to hear that. If it works for you, you may accept this as an answer. Upvoting will be possible soon.